# stringoutofboundexception in java (due to long string)

Tags: java

I am getting a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for a long string. Basically the program is reading string from text file and for some reason i am getting error when I use long strings. For e.g. if use `a=b+c` or `a=b` or `a=b+c-d*a` this all works but when i put long strings such as "programming" or "javatutorial" this gives me a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. At first I thought this was due to the fact that I am not checking whether or not x is empty but that is not the case this is occurring due to the length of the string itself. I would appreciate if someone could help.

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
      String x = scan.nextLine(); 

      try
      {
          if(!x.isEmpty())
          {
              char ch=x.charAt(0);
              s=String.valueOf(ch);
          }
      }

      catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException siobe)
      {
          System.out.println("invalid input");
      }
}
```

Comment: Please provide stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)

Comment: Provide the full trace.... This exception cannot occur in the code you have provided...

Comment: this is all i got in linux.

Comment: Your last comment is unintelligible.  We suspect that the code you posted isn't what is generating the error.  Can you show us the full stack trace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at parser.A(parser.java:70)
 at parser.main(parser.java:53)

Comment: Do you know exactly on which input line exception occurs?

Comment: @user5022426 Exception says `String index out of range: 11` but in your given code you are calling `x.charAt(0);` so there is no way 0 become 11 in chaAt so is any where else you are calling `charAt` method in you code.

Comment: You need to provide the code for your Parser class; That is where the error is occurring.

Comment: @ Mateusz Sroka since the program is of top down parsing the string will be checked against the condition from top to bottom regardless of each new character. The error that i have posted shows that i have to file this at line 70 which is where my first condition is located.

Comment: Yeah, author changed if(!x.isEmpty()) statement. Previously it has also something with OR in it maybe he didn't changed this in code?

Comment: @Haloboy oh wish i could do that it's a college project which is due in today and i m sure my college buddies may be googling badly. This is my hard work and would love to paste everything to get query solved but my hands are tight

Comment: @SumitSingh yes i am calling x.charat() at many places

Comment: @user5022426 By input I meant input file with your data that is actually parsed.

Comment: @MateuszSroka that OR condition was something that i was trying myself but it didn't work

Comment: @user5022426 please post lines around 53 form parser.java file

Comment: @MateuszSroka line 53 has nothing and line 70 has }

Comment: @user5022426 use eclipse or there tool to debug you code step by step see where this exception is coming and also see the what parameter  you are passing to `charAt()`

Comment: programming
javatutorial---->these are the inputs that i am trying

Comment: @SumitSingh good idea thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the partial code you provided, all we can tell you is that the exception is being thrown because you are using the method:

```
String.charAt(int index)
```

on a String that does not have a character at the 'index'-th position.

For example, if String word = "cat", then word.charAt(8) would throw an exception because 'cat' only has three characters.

Search through your code for all the places that you used the charAt(int index) method and test that 'index' is indeed less than String.length(). Your error shows an argument of '11', so you can narrow your search to the location where you called the charAt() method with an index of 11. (This may be inside a loop).